# How to encapulate user function from subclass in C++

Tags: c++, oop, encapsulation, composition

For explain my problem, I wrote some example.

```cpp
class Product {
public:
  Product(Module& module, Config module_cfg) : module_(module) {
    module_.SetConfig(module_cfg);
  }

  void Work() {
    module_.Work();
  }

private:
  Module& module_;
};

class Module {
public:
  void SetConfig(Config cfg) {
    cfg_ = cfg;
  }

  virtual void Work() = 0;

protected:
  Config cfg_;
};


class ModuleA : public Module {
  void Work() override {
    cfg_.GetSomething(); // use config
  }
};
```

1. "Product" has a "Module" as composition.
2. "Module" works with "Config".
3. "Module" is parent class of "ModuleA".

I want to encapsulate "SetConfig()" method from "ModuleA"!!

On the other words, is there way to hide user functions from an inherited class?

Comment: Do you mean to stop `ModuleA`'s own methods calling `SetConfig()`? That can't be done; code within subclasses always gets the same or greater access rights than public users of instances. IIRC you can hide inherited functionality in subclasses, so users won't be able to call `SetConfig()` on a `ModuleA` instance, but they _could_ if they simply cast it to the base class... So I would suggest re-evaluating your design and why you think you need this, or just telling users not to do the daft things.

Comment: Even if `SetConfig` were hidden, `ModuleA` can still assign to `cfg`

Comment: If you make `SetConfig` virtual then you can override it in `ModuleA`, and "encapsulate" it that way. Not sure if that's what you want though.

Comment: Yeah, I did think that you can override it to `throw` or whatever, so at least stopping users from changing the config, but that seems horrible, so I didn't mention it ;-)

Comment: Or perhaps `SetConfig` should not be public to begin with, and have `Module` should have `Product` be a friend?

Comment: How often do you have to change config for a module? If it is not often than you can remove `SetConfig` method and set up the config class for `Module` using constructor. Then you can only provide configured module for a product.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My question is a way to prevent calling `SetConfig()` in implementation of `ModuleA`. Just I don't want to call `SetConfig()` as mistake when someone implements `ModuleB` or `ModuleC`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the function `private`, not `public` (or `protected`).

Then, derived classes won't be able to access it.

Of course, nobody else (except the base class the function's in) will be able to access it either. But it doesn't make sense to permit "global" access without permitting access from derived classes.

If you *do* want `SetConfig` to be public, then just don't call it from the derived class if you don't want to. If you do it by mistake, fix the mistake.

Comment: No object will be able to acces the method, only functions inside the class...

Comment: @anastaciu Right, which may be what is wanted. If it isn't, I already discussed that in the final paragraph.

Comment: "But it doesn't make sense to permit "global" access without permitting access from derived classes", it does make sense if you want to create objects of the base class, what he doesn't want is to derived classes to access the method, as he says "On the other words, is there way to hide user functions from an inherited class?".

Comment: @anastaciu And the answer is exactly what I said: there are two options, and doing what they want is not one of them.